# Toggle Both on Span and List Item

Tags: jquery

In the demo over here http://jsfiddle.net/ewk9jmxx/2/ when I click on 'First Child' or 'Second Child' it toggles between blue and red color. However when I click on the '+' symbol (span) besides 'First Child' ; the color does not toggle. How do I make the toggle occur in both conditions ie. when I click the span as well when I click the 'First Child' element

My HTML structure is as follows:

```
<ul id="Budor">
<li class="L-1">First
    <span class='jor'>+</span>
    <ul>
       <li class="L-2">First Child
           <span class='jor'>+</span>
          <ul>
              <li>abc</li>
              <li>xyz</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Here's the code:

```
$('#Budor li').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow', function () {                    
        $(e.target)
            .toggleClass('opened', $(this).is(':visible'));
    });                
});
```

Comment: Add in the javascript code in the question

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#Budor ul').addClass('handle closed');

$('#Budor li').on('click', function (e) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // don't close parent on child click
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow', function () {                    
        if($(e.target).is('li')) // if clicked on First
            $(e.target).toggleClass('opened', $(this).is(':visible'));
        else if($(e.target).is('span')) // if clicked on + (child of First)
            $(e.target).parent('li').toggleClass('opened', $(this).is(':visible'));

    });                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is event target get pointed to span element when clicking on +, so we need to put an element type check so that we change class only when its element 'li'.  Find below updated code. HTH -

```
$('#Budor ul').addClass('handle closed');

$('#Budor li').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // prevent links from toggling the nodes
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow', function () {                    
        if ( $(e.target).is( "li" ) ) {
            $(e.target)
            .toggleClass('opened', $(this).is(':visible'));
        } else {
            $($(e.target).parent())
            .toggleClass('opened', $(this).is(':visible'));
        }
    });                
});
```

[Modified Version Link on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewk9jmxx/9/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify some things:

```
$("#Budor").addClass('closed');

$('#Budor').click(function (e) {
    $(e.target).find('ul').slideToggle('slow', function () {
        $(e.target).toggleClass('opened');
    });    
});
```

Check out here: http://jsfiddle.net/ewk9jmxx/11/

**EDIT**

Here is an updated version. Sorry, I haven't paid attention to that detail:

```
$("#Budor").addClass('opened');

$('#Budor').click(function (e) {
    $(e.target).find('ul').slideToggle('slow', function () {
        $(e.target).toggleClass('closed');
    });    
});

$('#Budor span').click(function (e) {
    $(e.target).parent('li').trigger('click');
});
```

Here it goes the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ewk9jmxx/16/

Comment: I cannot view the child items now when I click on '+'. Earlier I could use either '+' or click on 'First Child' to view subitems. How to fix that in your code?

Comment: @user195668 I update my answer. Please check it out.